# Significance of declaring a WPF event handler as 'async' in C# 5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, c#-5.0

Imagine a WPF code-behind event handler:

```
<Button Click="OnButtonClick" />
```

In C# 4 you would declare your handler as:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

In C# 5 you can declare an `async` handler

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

So what is WPF doing with this? A few minutes of searching about didn't turn anything up.

It seems that it's possible to perform UI updates after `await` statements. Does this imply that the task is continued on the Dispatcher thread?

If the `Task` raised an error, would it be raised through the WPF `Dispatcher`, or only via the `TaskScheduler`?

Are there any other interesting aspects to this that might be nice to understand?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may find my [async/await intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

An `async` method is re-written by the compiler to support the `await` operator. Every `async` method starts out synchronous (in this case, on the UI thread) until it `await`s some operation (that is not already completed).

By default, the context is saved, and when the operation completes, the rest of the method is scheduled to execute in that context. The "context" here is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. As Drew pointed out, WPF provides a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` which is tied to the WPF `Dispatcher`.

Regarding error handling:

When you `await` a `Task` inside a WPF `async void` event handler, the error handling goes like this:

- The `Task` completes with an error. The exception is wrapped into an `AggregateException`, like all `Task` errors.
- The `await` operator sees that the `Task` completed with an error. It unwraps the original exception and re-throws it, preserving the original stack trace.
- The `async void` method builder catches the exception escaping from an `async void` method and passes it to the `SynchronizationContext` that was active when the `async void` method started executing (in this case, the same WPF context).
- The exception is raised (with the original stack trace, and without any annoying `AggregateException` wrapping) on the `Dispatcher`.

This is rather convoluted, but the intent is to have exceptions raised from `async` event handlers be practically the same as exceptions raised from regular event handlers.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The fact that the initiator's context is saved is what I was missing. I guess I can't really think of any other approach that would make sense.

Answer (score 6):

A partial answer. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

> An async method that has a void return type can’t be awaited, and the caller of a void-returning method can't catch any exceptions that the method throws.

So any errors would only be available via the `TaskScheduler`.

Also, there's nothing XAML-specific going on with the event handler registration. It could have been done in code:

```
this.button.Click += OnButtonClick;
```

Or even as an async lambda:

```
this.button.Click += async (s,e) => { ... };
```

As for safety of UI updates after an `await`, it seems that the continuation is executed within [`SynchronisationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx), which is set per thread. In WPF, this is a [`DispatcherSynchronisationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.aspx) that's coupled to the WPF `Dispatcher` that pumped the event in the first place.