# How to run and interact with an async Task from a WPF gui

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have a WPF GUI, where I want to press a button to start a long task without freezing the window for the duration of the task. While the task is running I would like to get reports on progress, and I would like to incorporate another button that will stop the task at any time I choose.

I cannot figure the correct way to use async/await/task. I can't include everything I've tried, but this is what I have at the moment.

A WPF window class :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly otherClass _burnBabyBurn = new OtherClass();
    internal bool StopWorking = false;
        
    //A button method to start the long running method
    private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        Task slowBurn = _burnBabyBurn.ExecuteLongProcedureAsync(this, intParam1, intParam2, intParam3);
            
        await slowBurn;
    }
        
    //A button Method to interrupt and stop the long running method
    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopWorking = true;
    }

    //A method to allow the worker method to call back and update the gui
    internal void UpdateWindow(string message)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = message;
    }
}
```

And a class for the worker method:

```
class OtherClass
{
    internal Task ExecuteLongProcedureAsync(MainWindow gui, int param1, int param2, int param3)
    {       
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();       
             
        //Start doing work
        gui.UpdateWindow("Work Started");        
             
        While(stillWorking)
        {
        //Mid procedure progress report
        gui.UpdateWindow("Bath water n% thrown out");        
        if (gui.StopTraining) return tcs.Task;
        }
             
        //Exit message
        gui.UpdateWindow("Done and Done");       
        return tcs.Task;        
    }
}
```

This runs, but the WPF function window is still blocked once the worker method starts.

I need to know how to arrange the async/await/task declarations to allow

A) the worker method to not block the gui window
B) let the worker method update the gui window
C) allow the gui window to stop interrupt and stop the worker method

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Long story short:

```
private async void ButtonClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // modify UI object in UI thread
    txt.Text = "started";

    // run a method in another thread
    await HeavyMethodAsync(txt);
    // <<method execution is finished here>>

    // modify UI object in UI thread
    txt.Text = "done";
}

// This is a thread-safe method. You can run it in any thread
internal async Task HeavyMethodAsync(TextBox textBox)
{
    while (stillWorking)
    {
        textBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // UI operation goes inside of Invoke
            textBox.Text += ".";
            // Note that: 
            //    Dispatcher.Invoke() blocks the UI thread anyway
            //    but without it you can't modify UI objects from another thread
        });
        
        // CPU-bound or I/O-bound operation goes outside of Invoke
        // await won't block UI thread, unless it's run in a synchronous context
        await Task.Delay(51);
    }
}
```

```
Result:
started....................done
```

---

Read on, if you're not sure how to write `async` code.

Otherwise, skip to "WPF GUI" section, if you're not sure how to run UI operations in another thread.

---

## `async` and `await`:

### Basics of `async` and `await`

1. You can only `await` in an `async` method.
2. You can only `await` an awaitable object (i.e. `Task`, `ValueTask`, `Task<T>`, `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, etc.) These objects wrap around the return type of an `async` method and `await` keyword unwraps them. (see Wrapping and Unwrapping section)
3. Asynchronous method names should **always** end with `Async` to increase readability and to prevent mistakes.

   ```
   // Synchronous method:
   TResult MethodName(params) { }

   // Asynchronous method:
   async Task<TResult> MethodNameAsync(params) { }
   ```

### The magic of `async` and `await`

1. The `async-await` syntactic feature, uses a state-machine to let the compiler **give up** and **take back** the control over the `awaited Task` in an `async` method.
2. The execution waits at `await` for the task to finish and returns back its results, **without blocking** the main thread.
3. `Task.Run` queues a `Task` in the **thread pool**. *(Unless the it's a [pure](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) operation.)*
   *i.e. The `async` method **does not** run in another thread. `async` and `await` by themselves don't have anything to do with thread creation.*

So

When you **run a `Task`** (e.g. `Task.Run(action)`) you (re)use a thread for that action. And you can put that task in an `async` method to control its flow. By putting `async` in the method signature you tell the compiler to use state-machine to control the flow of that method (this does not mean threading at all). And by `await`ing the task you prevent the execution flow within that method from moving past the `await`ed statement **without blocking UI thread**. If you want to pass the flow onto the caller then the `async` method itself can become a `Task` so you'll be able to cascade the same pattern out into the caller and so forth:

```
async Task Caller() { await Method(); }
async Task Method() { await Inner(); }
async Task Inner() { await Task.Run(action); }
```

The event handler looks like the code below.

Two possible cases for presense of async in the signature of `ExecuteLongProcedure` (case 1 and 2) and `MyButton_ClickAsync` (case A and B) are explained:

```
private async void MyButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //queue a task to run on threadpool

    // 1. if ExecuteLongProcedure is a normal method and returns void
    Task task = Task.Run(()=>
        ExecuteLongProcedure(this, intParam1, intParam2, intParam3)
    );
    // or
    // 2. if ExecuteLongProcedure is an async method and returns Task
    Task task = ExecuteLongProcedureAsync(this, intParam1, intParam2, intParam3);

    // either way ExecuteLongProcedure is running asynchronously here
    // the method will exit if you don't wait for the Task to finish

    // A. wait without blocking the main thread
    //  -> requires MyButton_ClickAsync to be async
    await task;
    // or
    // B. wait and block the thread (NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL)
    // -> does not require MyButton_ClickAsync to be async
    task.Wait();
}
```

---

## Async method return types:

Suppose you have the following declaration:

```
private async ReturnType MethodAsync() { ... }
```

- If `ReturnType` is `Task` then `await MethodAsync();` returns `void`
- If `ReturnType` is `Task<T>` then `await MethodAsync();` returns a value of type `T`

  This is called **Unwrapping**, see the next section (Wrapping and Unrwapping).
- If `ReturnType` is `void` **you can't `await` it**

  - If you try writing `await MethodAsync();`, you will get a compile error saying:

  > cannot await void

  - You can **only** *fire and forget* i.e. just call the method normally: `MethodAsync();` and then go on with your life.
  - The `MethodAsync` execution will be synchronous, however since it has `async` it will allow you to take advantage of the magic, i.e. you can write `await task` within the method to control the flow of execution.
  - **This is how WPF handles your button click event handler,** obviously because your event handler returns `void`.

> The return type of an async method must be `void`, `Task`, `Task<T>`, a task-like type, `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, or `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`

---

## Wrapping and Unrwapping:

### Wrapping:

`async` methods wrap their return values in a `Task`.

E.g., this method wraps a `Task` around an `int` and returns it:

```
//      async Task<int>
private async Task<int> GetOneAsync()
{
    int val = await CalculateStuffAsync();
    return val;
//  returns an integer
}
```

### Unwrapping:

To retrieve or *unwrap* the value which is *wrapped* inside a `Task<>`:

- asynchronous option: `await`
- synchronous option: `task.Result` or `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` or `task.WaitAndUnwrapException()` or read [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

e.g. `await` unwraps the `int` out of the `Task`:

```
Task<int> task = GetOneAsync();
int number = await task;
//int     <-       Task<int>
```

### Different ways to wrap and unwrap:

```
private Task<int> GetNumber()
{
    Task<int> task;

    task = Task.FromResult(1); // the correct way to wrap a quasi-atomic operation, the method GetNumber is not async
    task = Task.Run(() => 1); // not the best way to wrap a number

    return task;
}

private async Task<int> GetNumberAsync()
{
    int number = await Task.Run(GetNumber); // unwrap int from Task<int>

    // bad practices:
    // int number = Task.Run(GetNumber).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // sync over async
    // int number = Task.Run(GetNumber).Result; // sync over async
    // int number = Task.Run(GetNumber).Wait(); // sync over async

    return number; // wrap int in Task<int>
}
```

Still confused? Read async return types on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types).

> To unwrap a task result, **Always** try to use `await` instead of `.Result` otherwise there will be no asynchronous benefit but only asynchronous disadvantages. The latter is called "sync over async".

### Note:

`await` is a asynchronous and is different from `task.Wait()` which is synchronous. But they both do the same thing which is waiting for the task to finish.

`await` is a asynchronous and is different from `task.Result` which is synchronous. But they both do the same thing which is waiting for the task to finish and unwrapping and returning back the results.

To have a wrapped value, you can always use `Task.FromResult(1)` instead of creating a new thread by using `Task.Run(() => 1)`.

`Task.Run` is newer (.NetFX4.5) and simpler version of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

---

## WPF GUI:

This is where I explain **how to run UI operations in another thread.**

### Blocking:

First thing you need to know about **WPF async event handlers** is that the `Dispatcher` will provide a [synchronization context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8). [Explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12556993/366064)

CPU-bound or IO-bound operations such as `Sleep` and `task.Wait()` will **block and consume** the thread even if they are called in a method with `async` keyword. but `await Task.Delay()` tells the state-machine to **stop** the flow of execution on the thread so it does not consume it; meaning that the thread resources can be used elsewhere:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//stops, blocks and consumes threadpool resources
        await Task.Delay(1000);//stops without consuming threadpool resources
        Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));//does not stop but consumes threadpool resources
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));//literally the WORST thing to do
}
```

### Thread Safety:

If you have to access GUI asynchronously (inside `ExecuteLongProcedure` method), **invoke** any operation which involves modification to any non-thread-safe object. For instance, any WPF GUI object must be invoked using a `Dispatcher` object which is associated with the GUI thread:

```
void UpdateWindow(string text)
{
    //safe call
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        txt.Text += text;
    });
}
```

However, If a task is started as a result of a **property changed callback** from the ViewModel, there is no need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` because the callback is actually executed from the UI thread.

> **Accessing collections on non-UI Threads**

> WPF enables you to access and modify data collections on threads other than the one that created the collection. This enables you to use a background thread to receive data from an external source, such as a database, and display the data on the UI thread. By using another thread to modify the collection, your user interface remains responsive to user interaction.

[Value changes fired by INotifyPropertyChanged are automatically marshalled back onto the dispatcher.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553471/366064)

[How to enable cross-thread access](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-part-7-accessing-collections-on-non-ui-threads/)

Remember, `async` method itself runs on the main thread. So this is valid:

```
private async void MyButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txt.Text = "starting"; // UI Thread
    await Task.Run(()=> ExecuteLongProcedure1());
    txt.Text = "waiting"; // UI Thread
    await Task.Run(()=> ExecuteLongProcedure2());
    txt.Text = "finished"; // UI Thread
}
```

Another way to invoke UI operations from UI thread is to use `SynchronizationContext` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24672061/366064). `SynchronizationContext` is a stronger abstraction than `Dispatcher` and it's cross-platform.

```
var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
while (stillWorking)
{
    uiContext.Post(o =>
    {
        textBox.Text += ".";
    }, null);
    await Task.Delay(51);
}
```

### Patterns:

#### Fire and forget pattern:

For obvious reasons this is how your WPF GUI event handlers such as `Button_ClickAsync` are called.

```
void Do()
{
    // CPU-Bound or IO-Bound operations
}
async void DoAsync() // returns void
{
    await Task.Run(Do);
}
void FireAndForget() // not blocks, not waits
{
    DoAsync();
}
```

#### Fire and observe:

Task-returning methods are better since unhandled exceptions trigger the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
void Do()
{
    // CPU-Bound or IO-Bound operations
}
async Task DoAsync() // returns Task
{
    await Task.Run(Do);
}
void FireAndWait() // not blocks, not waits
{
    Task.Run(DoAsync);
}
```

#### Fire and wait synchronously while wasting thread resources:

This is known as *Sync over async*, it is a synchronous operation but it uses more than one thread which may cause starvation. This happens when you call `Wait()` or try to read results directly from `task.Result` before the task is finished.

(**AVOID THIS PATTERN**)

```
void Do()
{
    // CPU-Bound or IO-Bound operations
}
async Task DoAsync() // returns Task
{
    await Task.Run(Do);
}
void FireAndWait() // blocks, waits and uses 2 more threads. Yikes!
{
    var task = Task.Run(DoAsync);
    task.Wait();
}
```

---

#### Is that all to it?

No. There is a lot more to learn about `async`, its **context** and its **continuation**. This [blogpost](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md) is especially recommended.

#### Task uses Thread? Are you sure?

Not necessarily. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614146/366064) to know more about the true face of `async`.

[Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) has explained `async-await` perfectly. He also explains in his [other blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) when there is no thread involved.

#### Read more

[ValueTask and Task](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html)

[MSDN explains `Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[MSDN explains `async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

[how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

[`async await` - Behind the scenes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh191443(v=vs.120))

[`async await` - FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/12/asyncawait-faq/)

Make sure you know the difference between Asynchronous, Parallel and Concurrent.

You may also read [a simple asynchronous file writer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844248/366064) to know where you should concurrent.

Investigate [concurrent namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Ultimately, read this e-book: [Patterns_of_Parallel_Programming_CSharp](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 15):

Your use of `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is incorrect. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is a way to create [TAP-compatible wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx) for asynchronous operations. In your `ExecuteLongProcedureAsync` method, the sample code is all CPU-bound (i.e., inherently synchronous, not asynchronous).

So, it's much more natural to write `ExecuteLongProcedure` as a synchronous method. It's also a good idea to use standard types for standard behaviors, in particular [using `IProgress<T>` for progress updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CancellationToken` for cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
internal void ExecuteLongProcedure(int param1, int param2, int param3,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<string> progress)
{       
  //Start doing work
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report("Work Started");

  while (true)
  {
    //Mid procedure progress report
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report("Bath water n% thrown out");
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }

  //Exit message
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report("Done and Done");
}
```

Now you have a more reusable type (no GUI dependencies) that uses the appropriate conventions. It can be used as such:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  readonly otherClass _burnBabyBurn = new OtherClass();
  CancellationTokenSource _stopWorkingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

  //A button method to start the long running method
  private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var progress = new Progress<string>(data => UpdateWindow(data));
    try
    {
      await Task.Run(() => _burnBabyBurn.ExecuteLongProcedure(intParam1, intParam2, intParam3,
          _stopWorkingCts.Token, progress));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      // TODO: update the GUI to indicate the method was canceled.
    }
  }

  //A button Method to interrupt and stop the long running method
  private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    _stopWorkingCts.Cancel();
  }

  //A method to allow the worker method to call back and update the gui
  void UpdateWindow(string message)
  {
    TextBox1.Text = message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a simplified version of the most popular answer here by Bijan. I simplified Bijan's answer to help me think through the problem using the nice formatting provided by Stack Overflow.

By carefully reading and editing Bijan's post I finally understood: [How to wait for async method to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete)

In my case the chosen answer for that other post is what ultimately led me to solve my problem:

"Avoid `async void`. Have your methods return `Task` instead of `void`. Then you can `await` them."

**My simplified version of Bijan's (excellent) answer follows:**

1) This starts a task using async and await:

```
private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // if ExecuteLongProcedureAsync has a return value
    var returnValue = await Task.Run(()=>
        ExecuteLongProcedureAsync(this, intParam1, intParam2, intParam3));
}
```

2) This is the method to execute asynchronously:

```
bool stillWorking = true;
internal void ExecuteLongProcedureAsync(MainWindow gui, int param1, int param2, int param3)
{
    //Start doing work
    gui.UpdateWindow("Work Started");

    while (stillWorking)
    {
        //put a dot in the window showing the progress
        gui.UpdateWindow(".");

        //the following line blocks main thread unless
        //ExecuteLongProcedureAsync is called with await keyword
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    gui.UpdateWindow("Done and Done");
}
```

3) Invoke the operation which involves a property from gui:

```
void UpdateWindow(string text)
{
    //safe call
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        txt.Text += text;
    });
}
```

Or,

```
void UpdateWindow(string text)
{
    //simply
    txt.Text += text;
}
```

Closing comments) In most cases you have two methods.

- First method (`Button_Click_3`) calls the second method and has the `async` modifier which tells the compiler to enable threading for that method.

  - `Thread.Sleep` in an `async` method blocks the main thread. but awaiting a task does not.
  - Execution stops on current thread (second thread) on `await` statements until task is finished.
  - You can't use `await` outside an `async` method
- Second method (`ExecuteLongProcedureAsync`) is wrapped within a task and returns a generic `Task<original return type>` object which can be instructed to be processed asynchronously by adding `await` before it.

  - Everything in this method in executed asynchronously

### Important:

Liero brought up an important issue. When you are Binding an element to a ViewModel property, the *property changed callback* is executed in UI thread. So there is no need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`. [Value changes fired by INotifyPropertyChanged are automatically marshalled back onto the dispatcher.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553471/366064)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example using `async/await`, `IProgress<T>` and `CancellationTokenSource`. These are the modern C# and .Net Framework language features that you *should* be using. The other solutions are making my eyes bleed a bit.

### Code Features

- Count to 100 over a period of 10 seconds
- Display progress on a progress bar
- Long running work (a 'wait' period) performed without blocking the UI
- User triggered cancellation
- Incremental progress updates
- Post operation status report

### The view

```
<Window x:Class="ProgressExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="93.258" Width="316.945">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Button_Start" Click="Button_Click">Start</Button>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar_Progress" Height="20"  Maximum="100"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button_Cancel" IsEnabled="False" Click="Button_Cancel_Click">Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### The code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource currentCancellationSource;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Enable/disabled buttons so that only one counting task runs at a time.
            this.Button_Start.IsEnabled = false;
            this.Button_Cancel.IsEnabled = true;

            try
            {
                // Set up the progress event handler - this instance automatically invokes to the UI for UI updates
                // this.ProgressBar_Progress is the progress bar control
                IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(count => this.ProgressBar_Progress.Value = count);

                currentCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                await CountToOneHundredAsync(progress, this.currentCancellationSource.Token);

                // Operation was successful. Let the user know!
                MessageBox.Show("Done counting!");
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Operation was cancelled. Let the user know!
                MessageBox.Show("Operation cancelled.");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Reset controls in a finally block so that they ALWAYS go 
                // back to the correct state once the counting ends, 
                // regardless of any exceptions
                this.Button_Start.IsEnabled = true;
                this.Button_Cancel.IsEnabled = false;
                this.ProgressBar_Progress.Value = 0;

                // Dispose of the cancellation source as it is no longer needed
                this.currentCancellationSource.Dispose();
                this.currentCancellationSource = null;
            }
        }

        private async Task CountToOneHundredAsync(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                // This is where the 'work' is performed. 
                // Feel free to swap out Task.Delay for your own Task-returning code! 
                // You can even await many tasks here

                // ConfigureAwait(false) tells the task that we dont need to come back to the UI after awaiting
                // This is a good read on the subject - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
                await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // If cancelled, an exception will be thrown by the call the task.Delay
                // and will bubble up to the calling method because we used await!

                // Report progress with the current number
                progress.Report(i);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Cancel the cancellation token
            this.currentCancellationSource.Cancel();
        }
    }
```